# Specific isomorphism between presentations of fundamental group of figure eight knot complement

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I'd like to find a specific isomorphism between the following finitely presented groups, (hopefully up to conjugation) preserving the meridian and longitude. Capital letters denote inverses.

1. Unsimplified fundamental group computed by SnapPy, with generators $a, b, c$ and relations $BabC, CaBcA$. The meridian is $Ab$ and the longitude is $cAcBaCbAb$.
2. Fundamental group provided by Khoi's paper *A cut-and-paste method for computing the Seifert volumes*, page 795, with generators $x, y$ and relation $xYXyxYxyXY$. The meridian is $x$ and the longitude is $yXYxxYXy$.

There is also a simplified fundamental group computed by SnapPy, with generators $a, b$ and relation $abbbaBAAB$. The meridian is $ABB$ and the longitude is $BAbabABa$. The simplification isomorphism is provided by SnapPy.

Background:
SnapPy computes the fundamental group via the dual 2-skeleton of a triangulation, while Khoi's presentation comes from the knot itself as a 2-bridge knot. It seems to be hard to translate one's generators to the other presentation.

I installed GAP but unfortunately the algorithm there works only for finite groups. Here are some possibly useful codes.

```
F:=FreeGroup(2);
khoi:=F/[F.1*F.2^-1*F.1^-1*F.2*F.1*F.2^-1*F.1*F.2*F.1^-1*F.2^-1];
G:=FreeGroup(3);
snap:=G/[G.2^-1*G.1*G.2*G.3^-1,G.3^-1*G.1*G.2^-1*G.3*G.1^-1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to find isomorphisms between the two groups in Magma, using the function $\mathtt{SearchForIsomorphism}$.

I have found two isomorphisms that map $Ab$ to $x$, but I have not found any that map $$ to $$.

The two mapping $Ab$ to $x$ are:

(1) $a \to xYX$, $b \to xY$, $c \to Y$ with inverse $x \to Ab$, $y \to C$, which maps $$ to $Y x yX YX  y  x  Yx$;

and

(2) $a \to Y$, $b \to Yx$, $c \to XYx$ with inverse $x \to Ab$, $y \to A$, which maps $$ to $XYxyXYXy x Yxx$.